# How to search billions of items by tags (looking for optimal architecture)?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, architecture

I have a huge database of items, billions of entries:

> **t_item**
>
> *itemId* ...

Each *item* is marked with multiple *tags*:

> **t_tag**
>
> *tagId*     *tagName*
>
> **t_item_tag**
>
> *itemTagId [AI]*     *itemId*     *tagId*

Use-case scenario for end-user is simple:

> Select all items marked with particular tags and sort them by some attribute. E.g.:
>
> - select all *laptops (tag)* with *Core i7 processor (another tag)* and sort them by *rating (t_item table)*;
> - select all *yellow (tag)* *bags (tag)* made of *leather (tag)* and sort them by *price (t_item table)*.

Currently I am running that system on top of MySQL, but it start hittings it's limits. Main concern is that final sorting is done **Using temporary; Using filesort** and that's kinda slow.

What other architecture can I employ to handle my use-case and volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Using temp; Using filesort" is not the villain, the schema and indexes are.

This is optimal for `tags`:

```
CREATE TABLE Tags (
    item_id ...,
    tag ... -- either a string or a tag_id, it does not matter much,
    PRIMARY KEY(tag, item_id),  -- for clustering and searching
    INDEX(item_id)  -- for maintenance (eg deleting an item_id)
    -- no FOREIGN KEYs; they slow things down
    -- no AUTO_INCREMENT; it is a total waste here
) ENGINE=InnoDB; -- so PK will be clustered.
```

So, even with billions of rows, such a table will be very efficient to reach into -- all "Yellow" items will be "clustered" and require very few disk hits.

(You suggested `tag_id` and another table.  I *think* it is a toss-up as to whether that is better or not.)

*Count the disk hits -- they are the main performance metric for huge tables.*

For `select all laptops (tag) with Core i7 processor (another tag) and sort them by rating (t_item table);` --

```
SELECT i.id
    FROM Items AS i
    JOIN Tags  AS t1  ON t1.item_id = i.id
    JOIN Tags  AS t2  ON t2.item_id = i.id
    WHERE t1.tag = 'laptops'
      AND t2.tag = 'Core i7 processor'
    ORDER BY i.rating DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

If there are 2000 'laptops', that might be 20 disk blocks (count as 20 disk hits).  150 'Core i7 processor' might be 2 more disk hits.  If those lead to 70 'items', then you get 70 more disk hits because they are likely to be randomly located.  And yes, there will be a temp table (in RAM) and a filesort (but no physical "file") to sort 70 ids and deliver 10.

Yes, you will have to dynamically construct this `SELECT`.

I stopped short (fetching only i.id) for a couple of reasons...

What else is in `Items`?  Some big `TEXT` columns (`description`, etc)?  They are a nuisance; they clutter the effort.

The desire is to say `SELECT i.*` instead of `SELECT i.id`.  Let's see if we can compromise.

Suppose you have `INDEX(id, rating)`.  But there are good reasons to make a table with *only* `id` and `rating` -- you are changing that often, *and* we need to have a "small" table to work with for the lookup and sort of 70 ids by rating.

So, let's have two tables: `Items` -- `id`, description, etc., and `Ratings` with just:

```
CREATE TABLE Ratings (
    item_id -- 1:1 with `Items.id`
    rating ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now, change my first query to say `FROM Ratings` (instead of `FROM Items`).  Now, we still have to fetch 70 rows from that table, but because it is smaller, there is more likelihood of caching, hence it *may* involve less than 70 disk hits.

Then, we need the final fetch of *only* the 10 bulky things from `Items`.

Total:  20+2+70+10 = 102 disk hits, or about 1 second on plain old spinning drive; much faster on SSDs.  (Plus hopes that the largest number, 70, will be lower.)

Back to the filesort...  By having only 'small' columns (id, rating) and having only 70 'rows' to sort, the filesort will be an in-MEMORY structure that will take virtually no time to execute.  This is why I say to ignore the filesort.  And by arranging to fetch the bulky `description` *later*, I avoided hauling it through the filsort, that would almost definitely force the tmp table to be MyISAM, not MEMORY.

Since you mentioned sorting by either Rating or Price, perhaps this is good:

```
CREATE TABLE RatingsPrices (
    item_id ..., -- 1:1 with `Items.id`
    rating ...,
    price ...,
    INDEX(item_id, rating),  -- covering index for the main query
    INDEX(item_id, price),  -- covering index for the main query
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

There are probably more details and subtleties, but I hope these hints move you in a good direction.

Remember:  If the dataset is so big that even a working set won't fit in RAM, "count the disk hits".

Comment: Many thanks for the brilliant answer. I really enjoyed reading it and will definitely give all that ideas a try!

Comment: Want to thank you once again. I have implemented your idea and it works like a charm. Gave a rocket boost to the system and users are just happy with the page serving times.